# Odoo Inheriting fields and functionality

Tags: odoo

I am have made two different classes(model.Models). I have 10 fields in one class and I need to inherit only two fields in other class from the former one. Like I update two fields in one class , It automatically must be updated in next class. So please help me out. How should I need to inherit these two fields and their functionality?

This is the Odoo Framework.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code. Can you be more specific? Supply code and say what doesn't work and what you want to achieve. It's easier to answer that way ;)

Comment: This is an exact copy of [your question from a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428475/inheriting-two-fields-from-different-class) and you haven't added any information.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can use related fields to get values from another model. You can do this by defining a Many2one to the model and access field in that model using related fields.

example:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    _name = 'model.a'

    field1 = fields.Char()
    .....
    field10 = fields.Char()


class ModelB(models.Model):
    _name = 'model.b'

    model_a_id = fields.Many2one('model.a', string='Related Model')
    field1 = fields.Char(related='model_a_id.field1', string='field1')
    field2 = fields.Char(related='model_a_id.field2', string='field2')
```

You can access any field in model.a from model.b using related fields. If you change values of field1 or field2 from any of these models, the change will be reflected in both models. So if you don't want the user to change values of these model from model.b, you can make them readonly in that model.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Does I need to need two fields in Views.xml file of model.b ?

Comment: @rahulrawat yes, if you want the user to view both fields, then you need to show the fields in view. Don't want to add in view if you are just using for reference.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciable. But as I am showing it in the views.xml. It is appearing in only form view. But as I have been added tree view also. But it fields are not updating in tree view. It is only updating in form view. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have added my code views.xml file above. Please have a look and let me know. I would be grateful to you.

Comment: Please let me know why my fields are not updating in view. It is only updating it in form view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<record id="ping_tree_view_id" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">Ping tree view</field>
      <field name="model">ping.ping</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <tree string="Ping">
          <field name="model_a_id"/>
          <field name="Last_update"/>
          <field name="Last_attempt"/>

      </tree>
      </field>
    </record>
    <record id="ping_form_view_id" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">Ping form view</field>
      <field name="model">ping.ping</field>

      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Ping">
          <sheet>

            <group>
              <field name="model_a_id"/>
              <field name="Last_update"/>
              <field name="Last_attempt"/>
            </group>

          </sheet>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="ping_actions_win">
      <field name="name">Ping</field>
      <field name="res_model">ping.ping</field>

      <field name="view_type">form</field>


      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
```